# How is racket's repl evaluating these quoted expressions?

Tags: scheme, racket

I can't quite get my head around racket's REPL behaviour for the following input:

```
> 1     ;; Simple, 1 is self-evaluating
1
> '1    ;; (quote x) => x
1
> ''1   ;; ?? I expected '1
''1
> '''1  ;; ???
'''1
```

I tried writing a simple macro to test:

```
#lang racket

(define-syntax e
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((e x) (display (eval x )))))
```

but it also gave me unexpected output:

```
> (e 1)     ;;Self evaluating 
1
> (e '1)    ;;Evaluated '1 as 1
1
> (e ''1)   ;;Shouldn't ''1 have been evaluated only once to '1?
1
> (e '''1)
'1
```

So what extra step is racket's repl doing, and why doesn't my macro work like I expected it to?

Comment: The 3rd and 4th result looks very wrong. Chez and IronScheme behaves like I and you expect.

Comment: The repl prints the result as an expression that evaluates to the actual result. `display` does not so `(display ''a) => 'a`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has to do with the default behaviour of Racket's printer (which is used by the REPL for output; it's different from `display`). Run this, then try again:

```
(print-as-expression #f)
```

As for `(eval ''1)`, this has to do with the fact that `''1` is the same as `(quote (quote 1))`, which evaluates to `(quote 1)`, which when passed to `eval` then results in 1.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are saying that `''1` is evaluated once in the body of the macro and once by `eval`, but not in the macro call `(e ''1)`?

Comment: Right, macro "calls" don't evaluate anything. In fact, suppressing (or otherwise delaying) evaluation is a major point of using macros.